# Модель генерирует очень странные аудио файлы

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, tensorflow, librosa

учу модель GAN с целью замены звучания инструмента одного аудиофайла на звучание инструмента из другого. Обучение идет стабильно после изменений lr + кол-во эпох. Но модель генерирует очень странные аудиофайлы. Если без librosa.griffinlim - как-будто разговоры в спанчбобе по телефону. С - очень прыгающий звук. Помогите:

[image: Спектограмма сген. аудио]

````py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import librosa
import soundfile as sf
import random

def load_and_convert_to_spectrogram(audio_file):
    audio, sr = librosa.load(audio_file, sr=None)
    spectrogram = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=audio, sr=sr, n_fft=2048, hop_length=512, n_mels=128)
    return spectrogram

def concatenate_fragments(fragments):
    return np.concatenate(fragments, axis=1)

def mse_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)

source_audio_file = r"C:\Users\Bebrus\Desktop\MusicReplacementAI\Fluxxwave.wav"
target_audio_file = r"C:\Users\Bebrus\Desktop\MusicReplacementAI\dde.wav"

source_spectrogram = load_and_convert_to_spectrogram(source_audio_file)
target_spectrogram = load_and_convert_to_spectrogram(target_audio_file)

fragment_length = 128

def split_spectrogram(spectrogram, fragment_length):
    num_frames = spectrogram.shape[1]
    fragments = []
    for i in range(0, num_frames, fragment_length):
        if i + fragment_length <= num_frames:
            fragment = spectrogram[:, i:i + fragment_length]
            fragments.append(fragment)
    return fragments

source_fragments = split_spectrogram(source_spectrogram, fragment_length)
target_fragments = split_spectrogram(target_spectrogram, fragment_length)

X_train = []
y_train = []

for source_fragment, target_fragment in zip(source_fragments, target_fragments):
    if source_fragment.shape[1] < fragment_length:
        source_fragment = np.pad(source_fragment, ((0, 0), (0, fragment_length - source_fragment.shape[1])), mode='constant')
    if target_fragment.shape[1] < fragment_length:
        target_fragment = np.pad(target_fragment, ((0, 0), (0, fragment_length - target_fragment.shape[1])), mode='constant')


    X_train.append(source_fragment)
    y_train.append(target_fragment)

X_train = np.array(X_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)

print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0000000000000000000000000000000000001)

def build_generator(input_shape, lstm_units):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=lstm_units, return_sequences=True, input_shape=input_shape),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=lstm_units, return_sequences=True),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=512, activation='relu')),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=input_shape[1]))
    ])
    return model

def build_discriminator(input_shape):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=512, return_sequences=True, input_shape=input_shape),
        tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=512, activation='relu')),
        tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=512, activation='relu')),
        tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=352, activation='relu')),
        tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
    ])
    return model

def build_gan(generator, discriminator):
    discriminator.trainable = False
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([generator, discriminator])
    return model

def train_gan(generator, discriminator, gan, X_train, y_train, epochs, batch_size):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for _ in range(X_train.shape[0] // batch_size):
            idx = random.sample(range(X_train.shape[0]), batch_size)
            X_batch = X_train[idx]
            y_batch = y_train[idx]

            fake_data = generator.predict(X_batch)

            real_labels = np.ones((batch_size, X_train.shape[1]))
            fake_labels = np.zeros((batch_size, X_train.shape[1]))

            d_loss_real = discriminator.train_on_batch(X_batch, real_labels)
            d_loss_fake = discriminator.train_on_batch(fake_data, fake_labels)

            g_loss = gan.train_on_batch(X_batch, real_labels)

            print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs}, D Loss Real: {d_loss_real}, D Loss Fake: {d_loss_fake}, G Loss: {g_loss}")


lstm_units = 512
generator = build_generator(input_shape=(None, X_train.shape[1]), lstm_units=lstm_units)
discriminator = build_discriminator(input_shape=(None, X_train.shape[1]))
gan = build_gan(generator, discriminator)

discriminator.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error')

gan.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error')

train_gan(generator, discriminator, gan, X_train, y_train, epochs=890, batch_size=86)

predicted_fragments = generator.predict(y_train)
predicted_spectrogram = concatenate_fragments(predicted_fragments)

output_audio_file = "generated_audio.wav"
predicted_audio = librosa.griffinlim(predicted_spectrogram, hop_length=512)
sf.write(output_audio_file, predicted_audio, samplerate=44000)```
````

Comment: чем обоснован `learning_rate=0.0000000000000000000000000000000000001`?

Comment: Там было жуткое повышение числа  Fake Loss. С 0.20 до 5.00 за 100 эпох. Это уже была крайняя мера. Знаю, код ужасен скорее-всего